# Bootstrap 4-alpha-2 navbar with dropdown position issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav, bootstrap-4

[image: Bootstrap 4-alpha-2 navbar with dropdown position issues]

Above is a screenshot taken with the responsive design feature built into Safari on OS X. Below, is the code used to produce the navbar, as you can see, the dropdown menu on the right continues off the page. How can I prevent this?

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color: #ecf0f1">
    <a class="hidden-xs-down navbar-brand" href="/">
        Brand
    </a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-up">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                   id="user-menu"
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   href="#"
                >
                    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs-down">&nbsp;Work</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"
                     aria-labelledby="user-menu"
                >
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Services
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                   id="user-menu"
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   href="#"
                >
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs-down">&nbsp;Team</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"
                     aria-labelledby="user-menu"
                >
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>&nbsp;People
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                   id="user-menu"
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   href="#"
                >
                    <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs-down">&nbsp;Company</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"
                     aria-labelledby="user-menu"
                >
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;News
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
                   id="user-menu"
                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   href="#"
                >
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs-down">&nbsp;Username</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"
                     aria-labelledby="user-menu"
                >
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-inbox"></i>&nbsp;Inbox
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-header">Events</div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;All Events
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                       href="#"
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add the class `dropdown-menu-right` to the dropdown-menu element.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link"
               id="user-menu"
               data-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false"
               href="#"
            >
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs-down">&nbsp;Username</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                 aria-labelledby="user-menu"
            >
                <a class="dropdown-item"
                   href="#"
                >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add extra .dropdown-menu-right class to your .dropdown-menu element.

```
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
             aria-labelledby="user-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item"
               href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Services
            </a>
        </div>
```

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f0ajqebL/4/)

Comment: Thanks, I had just found the answer a few minutes before you posted that. I know the v4 docs are still in alpha but they are lacking good examples.